# Magento update: An error occurred while saving the URL rewrite

Tags: magento-1.9

After updating Magento 1.9.2.1 >> 1.9.2.2 I get stuck with the following error:

```
Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'product/2/8-1-2' for key 'UNQ_MAG_CORE_URL_REWRITE_ID_PATH_IS_SYSTEM_STORE_ID', query was: INSERT INTO `mag_core_url_rewrite` (`store_id`,`category_id`,`product_id`,`id_path`,`request_path`,`target_path`,`is_system`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`), `category_id` = VALUES(`category_id`), `product_id` = VALUES(`product_id`), `id_path` = VALUES(`id_path`), `request_path` = VALUES(`request_path`), `target_path` = VALUES(`target_path`), `is_system` = VALUES(`is_system`)' in /home/sntruck/domains/sn-truckstyling.com/public_html/webshop/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
```

How can I fix this (I don't have SSH access)

Answer (score 1):

Truncate the `core_url_rewrite` table in database and re-index data again.